# Likelihood ratio test pvalues in gtsummary

Tags: r, gtsummary

How do l incorporate likelihood ratio test p values in gtsummary output table?

```
library(gtsummary)

    trial %>% 
      select(response, grade) %>% 
      tbl_uvregression(
        method = glm,
        y = response,
        method.args = list(family = binomial),
exponentiate = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `add_global_p(test = "LR")` to add the LRT p-value. In the background, the function is using `car::Anova(mod = x, type = "III", test = "LR")` to calculate the p-value

```r
library(gtsummary)
#> #BlackLivesMatter

tbl <-
  trial %>% 
  select(response, grade) %>% 
  tbl_uvregression(
    method = glm,
    y = response,
    method.args = list(family = binomial)
  ) %>%
  add_global_p(test = "LR")

#> add_global_p: Global p-values for variable(s) `add_global_p(include = "grade")`
#> were calculated with
#>   `car::Anova(mod = x$model_obj, type = "III", test = "LR")`
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-05-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>